# Equivalent of csaps and ppval in python

Tags: python, matlab, numpy

I'm trying to convert some **matlab** code into python using **numpy** and **scipy**.

Here is the matlab code :

```
pp=csaps(Data(:,1),Data(:,2),0.9999);
new_data= ppval(pp,Data(:,1));
```

In python, I replace `csaps` by the `SmoothSpline` function from [pywafo](https://github.com/mikemt/pywafo/blob/master/pywafo/src/wafo/interpolate.py) library. But I'm not able to find any function to replace `ppval`.

Here is the current python code:

```
pp = SmoothSpline(Data[0], Data[1], 0.9999)
new_data = pp(Data[0]) # should use ppval?
```

Any idea? Thanks in advance!

Comment: could you briefly describe what that function would do?

Comment: Did you try [scipy.interpolate.PiecewisePolynomial](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.interpolate.PiecewisePolynomial.html)? Note the difference in input parameters' order.

Answer (score 0):

I havent used SmoothSpline from pywafo library but i have used UnivariateSpline from Scipy.
Here is a minimal working example from [Scipy Spline](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.interpolate.UnivariateSpline.derivative.html#scipy.interpolate.UnivariateSpline.derivative)

```
from scipy.interpolate import UnivariateSpline
x = np.linspace(0, 10, 70)
y = np.sin(x)
spl = UnivariateSpline(x, y, k=4, s=0)
```

you can obtain the value of the piecewise polynomial function MATLAB "ppval" as follows

```
spl(Data[0])
```

as you have rightly stated above