# Equivalent of csaps in Python

Tags: python, matlab

I'm looking to find the python equivalent of [CSAPS](https://in.mathworks.com/help/curvefit/csaps.html) in matlab. I've looked around and found this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22786153/equivalent-of-csaps-and-ppval-in-python) but I'm unable to download pywafo using pip. It throws up an error:`No matching distribution found for pywafo`

Can somone please help.

Answer (score 0):

[Thats because it's named just wafo](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/wafo)

Use:

```
pip install wafo==0.3.1
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for the answer, but its still not working. I get an error message when i do 'pip install wafo==0.3.1' or 'pip install wafo' saying 'failed with error code 1. I tried everything listed on the page https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35991403/python-pip-install-gives-command-python-setup-py-egg-info-failed-with-error-c  but still no luck.

Comment: perhaps some other package which has implementation similar to csaps in matlab

Comment: do you have a fortran + c compiler and numpy installed?

Comment: If you have you may have to use the wheel package like mentioned in the install section on the page I've linked

Comment: Also error code 1 could mean you don't have enough rights, you sure you've got admin/ sudo in your shell?
+ could you please post the error log?

Comment: I have gnu c,c++ and fortran compiler on my computer, i tried using the installation process as your link said it didnt work too. I have admin rights on my system, i pip-ed a few packages which installed properly. Now I feel really dumb but still cant get it to work. The error log is huge if i use pip install wafo==0.3.1, if use just wafo, i get this: WindowsError: [Error 3] The system cannot find the path specified: 'src\\wafo\\spectrum\\test/*.*' as a part of the error log. does this help? I can may be mail you the log?

Comment: Just had a quick look at it, look at l.558/ l.747. You may want to try the gnu-fortran compiler (just a guess tbh, but worth a try)
(I know you listed it in your comment above, but is it in PATH and stuff?)

Comment: Im on arch, but this is [my grep for fortran in the log](https://pastebin.com/PC11C3kp), as you can see no errors, so it does indeed seem like it's your fortran compiler (/ the fact that python doesn't find it).

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/145395/discussion-between-nimbus3000-and-encomiastical).