# How translate ppval and @() in Matlab to Python equivalent?

Tags: python-3.x, matlab, scipy

I have the following code:

```
from scipy.interpolate import UnivariateSpline
from scipy.optimize import fmin

a = UnivariateSpline(b,c) #Python

d = fmins(@(t) -ppval(a,t), someexpression); #Matlab where fmin is equivalent to fmins
```

How translate it to Python3?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`@(t) -ppval(a,t)` in Matlab is an anonymous function

You can denote things similarly using a [lambda function](https://www.w3schools.com/python/python_lambda.asp) in python.

By teh example [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22786153/equivalent-of-csaps-and-ppval-in-python) I see that the output of the `UnivariateSpline`
is callable, then the python analogous is `lambda t: -a(t)`.

But you will have more problem `fmins` is not define then you may want to check alternatives in [scipy.optimize](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/optimize.html) package.

Answer (score 2):

The documentation of [fmin](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.optimize.fmin.html) tells us that its first argument must be the function, the second argument the initial value, so it's exactly the same as in MATLAB. In that case you should be able to call

```
d = fmin(lambda x: -a(x), someexpression)
```

Comment: How about two arrays a and b for ppval(a, b)?

Comment: @HenDoNR What exactly do those arrays mean? Have you consulted the documentation? In MATLAB the first argument represents the piecewise polynomial and you defined that to be `a` in python.